# Creating constructor with pointer and pointer to pointer parameters in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, constructor

I want to initialize a `File` object which takes a pointer and pointer to pointer as an argument. Is this the correct way of implementing it?

```
//file.h
class File {
    public: File(string * , int, string * * , int);
    void clean();

    private: string * one;
    int size_one; //gives size of one array
    string * * two;
    int size_two; //gives size of *two array
}

//file.cpp
File::File(string * s1, int i1, string * * s2, int i2) {
    int k;
    one = new string[i1];
    for (k = 0; k < i1; k++) {
        one[k] = s1[k];
    }

    two = new string * [i2];
    for (k = 0; k < i2; k++) {
        two[k] = s2[k];
    }
}
```

How should I implement the `clean()` function which deletes both arrays?

Comment: I suggest [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) tutorial on dynamic memory.

Comment: This won't compile since `two[k]` is of `string*` type and `s1[k]` is `char`. Try to exaplain why you need this arguments, maybe there is a better solution (`vector` for example). However if you want to delete it you need to call `delete` on every `string*` and then on `string**`.

Comment: @NikolayKondratyev You are right. It should `s2[]`

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that s1 and s2 are "new" pointers, you just need to write :
one = s1 and two = s2, because the string datas are already allocated and encapsulated behind the address contained by s1 and s2 pointers.

If you want to clone s1 and s2 contents, one's implementation is correct.
With two, you need to specify if s2 is a pointer of pointers that you want to clone or not. So the solutions could be :

```
two = new string*[i2];
for ( int k(0) ; k < i2 ; ++k )
    two[k] = s1[k];
```

or

```
two = new string*[i2];
for ( int k(0) ; k < i2 ; ++k )
{
    two[k] = new string[yourDim];
    for ( int l(0) ; l < i2 ; ++l )
        two[k][l] = s2[k][l];
}
```

and if you want to clean the second case, you need to clean the array of array before the array.

```
for ( int k(0) ; k < i2 ; ++k )
    delete two[k];
delete two;
```

Comment: @ NikolayKondratyev "s1[k] is char" : (*s1)[k] is char but s1[k] is a string in an array.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How should I implement clean() function in the first case? Is it enough to write "delete []two"?

Comment: Yes it's enough : delete[] one; You can use delete[] two; because at this time, it contains deleted pointers.